# "Story View" field "Company or organization" does not render HTML link

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I would like to report a possible bug in page SO "Story View".

Steps to reproduce it:

- Open User Profile.
- Click tab "Story View".
- Add a Position.
- In field "Company or organization" enter a name which contain the following letters`""`, example `ITC "Company" Something else`.
- Save.
- Open User Profile and view "Time line".
- Name of the company appears but HTML link is not clickable.

Bug can be reproduced on Version Chrome 56.0.2924.87

Example of data:

Company or organization:

Institute C.F.P. E. "XXX"

Title :
Coder

Company website:
http://www.google.com/

HTML rendered:

```
<div class="timeline-item-text">

<div class="timeline-item-title">
         Coder at Institute C.F.P. E. "XXX"

</div>

    <div class="timeline-item-tags">
            <span class="post-tag">testing</span>
    </div>



        </div>
```

Comment: Is it rendered as a link in the markup? I can't currently repro, do you have examples that you can link to?

Comment: @DeanWard I made an edit including more information, let me know if you are able to reproduce it now. Thanks!

Comment: To render as a link it needs to have an image... I'm checking whether that's by design now!

Comment: Yes, that's by design; you need an image and a URL for it to render as a link because it links to a 'list' of other users in the company which requires both of those things.

Comment: @DeanWard Ok I tested using your information and link is rendered properly. I was not aware about this requirement. Thanks for your time.